# Android - Animated gif as Movie freezes and only shows a fraction of the image

Tags: java, android, view, gif

I'm struggling when extending the View class to create a view that plays two GIFs simultaneously. So far I've succeeded loading two Gifs from the assets, but I need the app to load them from a couple of URLs. This is what the app's showing right now, the two Gifs not moving, and actually just showing a tiny part of them.

[image: android gifs]
This is the code of the View:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class GifView extends View {
    long movieStart = 0;
    boolean processFinish = false;
    Movie [] bothMovies;
    boolean staticMode = false;
    private boolean done = false;
    Context ctx;

    public GifView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        new GetGifFromNetwork().execute();
        bothMovies = new Movie[2];
        ctx = context;
    }
    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        new GetGifFromNetwork().execute();
        bothMovies = new Movie[2];
        ctx = context;
    }
    public GifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        new GetGifFromNetwork().execute();
        bothMovies = new Movie[2];
        ctx = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        System.out.println("Drawing view");
        if(staticMode){
            System.out.println("Starting stuff, very quickly");
             getTheStuffInTheCanvas(canvas);
        }
        else{
            while(!done){
                if(processFinish){
                    System.out.println("Starting stuff");
                    getTheStuffInTheCanvas(canvas);
                    done = true;
                    staticMode = true;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    class GetGifFromNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Movie[]> {
        protected Movie[] doInBackground(Void... objects) {
            InputStream in,in2;
            System.out.println("Getting movie");
            try {
                System.out.println("Decoding movie 1");
                Movie movie1 = urlToMovie(new URL("http://10.254.26.28:8888/front.gif"));
                System.out.println("Decoding movie 2");
                Movie movie2 = urlToMovie(new URL("http://10.254.26.28:8888/back.gif"));
                System.out.println("Stream closed");
                processFinish = true;
                bothMovies = new Movie[]{movie1, movie2};
                return bothMovies;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Shit got fucked");

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Movie[] io) {
            System.out.println("Post execute...");
            super.onPostExecute(io);
            System.out.println("Process finished");
        }
    }
    protected void getTheStuffInTheCanvas(Canvas canvas){
        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        if(movieStart == 0){
            movieStart = now;   }
        int relTime;

        // Drawing first image
        relTime = (int)((now - movieStart) % bothMovies[0].duration());
        bothMovies[0].setTime(relTime);
        bothMovies[0].draw(canvas,0,0);

        // Now second image
        relTime = (int)((now - movieStart) % bothMovies[1].duration());
        bothMovies[1].setTime(relTime);
        bothMovies[1].draw(canvas,0,300);
        this.invalidate();
    }
    protected Movie urlToMovie(URL url) {
        System.out.println("Opening connection");
        URLConnection conn = null;
        Movie movie = null;
        try {
            conn = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            bis.mark(conn.getContentLength());

            movie = Movie.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Something wrong happened with the decoding");
        }

        return movie;

    }
}
```

EDIT: And here is the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MainActivity"
            />
    <view
            class="com.dansd.coketruck.GifView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:id="@+id/GIFSingle">
    </view>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load GIF to webview, it's quite simple, I don't know if two webviews will play gifs at the same time, but they should.

Comment: I started off with WebViews. The problem with that is that I want to be able to control the frames of the GIFs later, and as far as I know WebView only displays GIFs as you would see them in the browser right?

Comment: Could you give us your layout.xml file? Maybe there is mistake, you 
have no measure method in your View.  WebView can only display Gif as far as i know,there is no possible control over it.

Comment: I've added the xml to the bottom of the question. :)